# 'str' object not callable error when creating tkinter.Toplevel() object

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, popupwindow, toplevel

In this bit of code right here, I get the following error. I have searched all over SO and still have no idea why this is happening. Basically, I have an option in my menu bar to return home and it's supposed to pull up a prompt which asks if the user is sure they want to leave without submitting.

```
self.optionsMenu = tkinter.Menu(self, tearoff=0)  # creates 'Options' cascade
self.optionsMenu.add_command(label="Home", command=self.parent.returnHome)

...

def returnHome(self, *args):
    self.page = index.AdminApplication(self.parent)
    self.confirmLeave()


def confirmLeave(self, *args):
    confirmPopup = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
    confirmPopup.title("Confirm Leave Page")
    confirmPopup.tkraise(self.parent)
    question = tkinter.Label(confirmPopup, text="Are you sure you want to leave without submitting your bracket?", font=('Helvetica', '10'))
    question.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S+tkinter.W+tkinter.E)
    leave = tkinter.Button(confirmPopup, text="Leave", height=0, width=100, command=self.changeRootSettings(self.page))
    leave.grid(row=1, column=0)
    cancel = tkinter.Button(confirmPopup, text="Cancel", height=0, width=100, command=confirmPopup.destroy())
    cancel.grid(row=1, column=1)
    confirmPopup.focus_force()
```

error:

```
$ C:/Users/student/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/Users/student/Documents/BracketsTool/index.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\student\Documents\BracketsTool\CreateBracket.py", line 37, in returnHome
    self.confirmLeave()
  File "c:\Users\student\Documents\BracketsTool\CreateBracket.py", line 23, in confirmLeave
    confirmPopup = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __init__
    self.title(root.title())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Sidenote: I know the code won't actually do what I want it to yet, but I don't want to try anything because I can't test it without pulling up the window correctly first.

Comment: does your object have an attribute `title` which is a string?

Comment: What is `self.title`? It appears to be a string.

Comment: self.title is never in my code. That error message stems from the tkinter __init__.py file.

Comment: What is `self.parent`? Have you verified that it is what you assume it is?

Comment: Yes, it's an instance variable that is instantiated in my __init__ method to be the parent object